# yarn scripts local bin missing in PATH when installed outside of cwd

Tags: docker, node-modules, yarnpkg, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a docker container with yarn v1.22.19 installed. A `.yarnrc` file includes the line `--modules-folder /node_modules` to lift `node_modules` to the container's root directory. This is a workaround for a bind mount to the working directory erasing `node_modules` that were installed when the image is built.

The packages and binaries are installed properly in `/node_modules/.bin/`. The working directory is `/app`.

`yarn bin` returns the correct path to binary directory, and `yarn run <binary>` properly executes the binary. However, a yarn script which attempts to execute the local binary, such as `"dev": "vite dev --host"` errors with `/bin/sh: 1: vite: not found`.

Node module resolution checks for ancestor directories if there is no `node_modules` directory in the working directory. Even so, I tried to change the `NODE_PATH` to point to `/node_modules` and still no luck. Why does the yarn script have a different context than yarn commands? How can I point it to the correct local binary directory?

**EDIT:**

While `yarn bin` points to the correct local binary folder, the child process produced by `yarn run` to run a script defined in `package.json` injects `cwd/node_modules/.bin` into `PATH` instead of the specified `/node_modules/.bin`. I suspect this is a bug in older versions of yarn.

As a workaround, is there a way to prepend a command to the execution of yarn scripts defined in `pcakage.json`? Then I could just manually inject the correct path into the environment.

Comment: We need to know the PATH, not the NODE_PATH. The latter is used for loading libraries; the former is used for running commands. You're running a command here, so it's the PATH that matters.

Comment: Ah ok, so I guess yarn injects the wrong `path/to/node_modules/.bin` into the `PATH` variable of a child process running a yarn script?

`/app/node_modules/.bin` is present but `/node_modules/.bin` is not.

Is there a way to prepend all yarn scripts with a command to properly configure PATH?

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing the question so those details are on the record. Personally, I don't use yarn directly -- I [package software for Nix, using yarn2nix when that software was written in Javascript](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Node.js), so I'm not the right person to answer this one.

Comment: Appreciate it. I can't find anything in yarn v1 docs so I'll just be adding the correct local bin to `PATH` in the Dockerfile.